# Percentage of items from a sql union

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sccm

I'm trying to return a column called "Percent %" from a union of two tables within an SCCM database. The data I'm trying to return is the percentage of versions and I'm not entirely sure how to write the code. Here's what I have.

```sql
DECLARE @Collection varchar(10)
SET @Collection = 'CM1000XX'

SELECT  [Software Installed], 
        Publisher, 
        Version, 
        COUNT(*) AS 'Client Count'
        --,(STR((COUNT(v_R_System.ResourceID)*100.0/(SELECT COUNT(Add_Remove_Programs_DATA.ResourceID))))) AS 'Percent %'
FROM(
    SELECT      Add_Remove_Programs_DATA.displayname00  as 'Software Installed', 
            Add_Remove_Programs_DATA.publisher00    as 'Publisher', 
            Add_Remove_Programs_DATA.version00      as 'Version'            
FROM        v_R_System AS Sys
LEFT JOIN   v_fullcollectionmembership FCM
ON          FCM.resourceid = Sys.resourceid
INNER JOIN  Add_Remove_Programs_DATA 
ON          Sys.ResourceID = Add_Remove_Programs_DATA.MachineID 
WHERE       FCM.collectionid = @Collection      
AND         (Add_Remove_Programs_DATA.Displayname00 = 'Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus - en-us'
OR          Add_Remove_Programs_DATA.Displayname00 LIKE 'Microsoft Office Professional%')
AND         Add_Remove_Programs_DATA.Version00 LIKE '1%'

UNION ALL

SELECT      Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA.displayname00   as 'Software Installed', 
            Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA.publisher00     as 'Publisher',
            Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA.version00       as 'Version'
FROM        v_R_System AS Sys
LEFT JOIN   v_fullcollectionmembership FCM
            ON FCM.resourceid = Sys.resourceid
INNER JOIN  Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA 
ON          Sys.ResourceID = Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA.MachineID 
WHERE       FCM.collectionid = @Collection      
AND         (Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA.Displayname00 = 'Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus - en-us'
OR          Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA.Displayname00 LIKE 'Microsoft Office Professional%')
AND         Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA.Version00 LIKE '1%') AS x64
group by Version, [Software Installed], Publisher
order by Version
```

Any help or point in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First yo need to correct the number of columns at the second SELECT statement within the UNION, because the two statements used at the UNION must have the same number of columns.

Second, to get the percentage for the UNION, you have to do another SELECT  statement in which the table at the FROM will be the result of the UNION.

Then you need this

```
Select *, 
(
select s.'Client Count'*100 / (select sum('Client Count') from s)
) as 'Percent %'  
from (your query before) as s
```

Comment: The code as it stands I believe is giving me the correct data for the number of clients with a particular version of Microsoft Office installed. What I'm trying to figure out though and create a column for is what percentage of the client count returned from the whole client count returned.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
Java Version|Publisher|Client Count|Percent %
Java Auto Updater   Sun Microsystems, Inc.   3249   39.54%
Java(TM) 6 Update 24   Oracle   2641   32.14%
Java Auto Updater   Oracle Corporation   1586   19.30%

Comment: Java Version  Publisher  Client Count Percent %
<br>Java Auto Updater Sun Microsystems, Inc. 3249  39.54%</br>
<br>Java(TM) 6 Update 24 Oracle   2641  32.14%</br>
<br>Java Auto Updater Oracle Corporation 1586  19.30%</br>

Comment: I tried the suggestion but it gives an error I've copied the code here: [link](http://ideone.com/c6nrhd) the error is: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 43
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: remove the ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a view in the database that produces the union for me to remove the complexity v_Add_Remove_Programs. I'm going to work with that thank you for the help!